# Transition div from one background gradient to another

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to get a div to transition from one background gradient to another. I have a magnetic scroll effect setup so that when the user scrolls down, or hits the arrow key down, the h1 title changes and the background gradient slowly transitions to another gradient. I have the magnetic scroll and h1 effects working fine. I even have the background gradients changing when they're supposed to. The problem is that I need these transitions to be super smooth. Currently they flash to the next gradient. I've been trying all kinds of hacks for a couple weeks now and can't seem to get anything to work. Visit the project live at [alopexid.com](http://alopexid.com).

My jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$(document).foundation


//find page height
var windowHeight = $('html').height();
//find each line's section height
var pageHeight = windowHeight*7;

//script for scrolling text on home page.
$(window).scroll(function(event){
    var currentHeight = $('body').scrollTop();
    //load in static home page if bottom of scroll is reached
    //alert(currentHeight);
    //grad1
    if (currentHeight == 0 && currentHeight < windowHeight){
        //$(".home-gradient").css("background", "linear-gradient(135deg, #65c9de 0%, #cbd45a 100%)");
        $("#home-gradient").removeAttr('style');
        $(".home-gradient").removeClass('grad2');
        $(".home-gradient").addClass('grad1');
    }
    //grad2
    else if (currentHeight >= windowHeight && currentHeight < windowHeight*2){
        //$(".home-gradient").css("background", "linear-gradient(135deg,  #cbd45a 0%, #009688 100%)");
        $("#home-gradient").removeAttr('style');
        $(".home-gradient").removeClass('grad1');
        $(".home-gradient").removeClass('grad3');
        $(".home-gradient").addClass('grad2');
    }
    //grad3
    else if (currentHeight >= windowHeight*2 && currentHeight < windowHeight*3){
        //$(".home-gradient").css("background", "linear-gradient(135deg,  #009688 0%, #FFC107 100%)");
        $(".home-gradient").removeClass('grad2');
        $(".home-gradient").removeClass('grad4');
        $(".home-gradient").addClass('grad3');
    }
    //grad4
    else if (currentHeight >= windowHeight*3 && currentHeight < windowHeight*4){
        //$(".home-gradient").css("background", "linear-gradient(135deg,  #FFC107 0%, #E91E63 100%)");
        $(".home-gradient").removeClass('grad3');
        $(".home-gradient").removeClass('grad5');
        $(".home-gradient").addClass('grad4');
    }
    //grad5
    else if (currentHeight >= windowHeight*4 && currentHeight < windowHeight*5){
        //$(".home-gradient").css("background", "linear-gradient(135deg,  #E91E63 0%, #9C27B0 100%)");
        $(".home-gradient").removeClass('grad4');
        $(".home-gradient").removeClass('grad6');
        $(".home-gradient").addClass('grad5');
    }
    //grad6
    else if (currentHeight >= windowHeight*5 && currentHeight < windowHeight*6){
        //$(".home-gradient").css("background", "linear-gradient(135deg,  #9C27B0 0%, #65c9de 100%)");
        $(".home-gradient").removeClass('grad5');
        $(".home-gradient").addClass('grad6');
    }
    //grad1
    else if (currentHeight >= windowHeight*6) {
        $(".home-gradient").removeClass('grad6');
        $(".home-gradient").addClass('grad1');
        $("#scroll-text").text("We are Alopex.");
        $(".home-big-gradient").css("display", "none");
        $(".home-gradient").css("display", "block");
        $("#frame-logo").hide();
        $("#scroll-guide").hide();
        $(".header").show(1500);
        $("#skip-intro").hide();
        $('#weather-color').css('display', 'block');
        $('#scroll-text').css('display', 'block');
        window.magneticScroll = undefined;

        return;
    }
});
```

My HTML:

```
    <div class="home-gradient" id="home-gradient">
</div>
<div class="home-big-gradient">
    <h1 class="magnetic">We are Alopex.</h1>
    <h1 class="magnetic">A digital marketing firm.</h1>
    <h1 class="magnetic">Building websites & apps.</h1>
    <h1 class="magnetic">In Palmer, Alaska.</h1>
    <h1 class="magnetic">Some of us are designers.</h1>
    <h1 class="magnetic">Some of us are developers.</h1>
    <h1 class="magnetic">We are Alopex.</h1>
</div>
```

My CSS:

```
.home-gradient {
    background-size: cover;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: -1;
    opacity: .75;
    position: fixed;
}
.grad1 {
    background: rgb(101, 201, 222);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg,  rgba(101, 201, 222, 1) 0%, rgba(203, 212, 90, 1) 100%); /* FF3.6-15 *///rgba(101, 201, 222, 1) #65C9DE | rgba(203, 212, 90, 1) #CBD45A
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg,  rgba(101, 201, 222, 1) 0%, rgba(203, 212, 90, 1) 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
    background: linear-gradient(135deg,  rgba(101, 201, 222, 1) 0%, rgba(203, 212, 90, 1) 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, #65c9de 0%, #cbd45a 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#65c9de', endColorstr='#cbd45a',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 fallback on horizontal gradient */
}
.grad2 {
    background: rgb(203, 212, 90);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg,  rgba(203, 212, 90, 1) 0%, rgba(0, 150, 136, 1) 100%); /* FF3.6-15 *///rgba(203, 212, 90, 1) #CBD45A | rgba(0, 150, 136, 1) #009688
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg,  rgba(203, 212, 90, 1) 0%, rgba(0, 150, 136, 1) 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
    background: linear-gradient(135deg,  rgba(203, 212, 90, 1) 0%, rgba(0, 150, 136, 1) 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#cbd45a', endColorstr='#009688',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 fallback on horizontal gradient */
}
.grad3 {
    background: rgb(0, 150, 136);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg,  rgba(0, 150, 136, 1) 0%, rgba(255, 193, 7, 1) 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */// rgba(0, 150, 136, 1) #009688 | rgba(255, 193, 7, 1) #FFC107
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg,  rgba(0, 150, 136, 1) 0%, rgba(255, 193, 7, 1) 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
    background: linear-gradient(135deg,  rgba(0, 150, 136, 1) 0%, rgba(255, 193, 7, 1) 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#009688', endColorstr='#FFC107',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 fallback on horizontal gradient */
}
.grad4 {
    background: rgb(255, 193, 7);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg,  rgba(255, 193, 7, 1) 0%, rgba(233, 30, 99, 1) 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */// rgba(255, 193, 7, 1) #FFC107 | rgba(233, 30, 99, 1) #E91E63
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg,  rgba(255, 193, 7, 1) 0%, rgba(233, 30, 99, 1) 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
    background: linear-gradient(135deg,  rgba(255, 193, 7, 1) 0%, rgba(233, 30, 99, 1) 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#FFC107', endColorstr='#E91E63',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 fallback on horizontal gradient */
}
.grad5 {
    background: rgb(233, 30, 99);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg,  rgba(233, 30, 99, 1) 0%, rgba(156, 39, 176, 1) 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */// rgba(233, 30, 99, 1) #E91E63 | rgba(156, 39, 176, 1) #9C27B0
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg,  rgba(233, 30, 99, 1) 0%, rgba(156, 39, 176, 1) 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
    background: linear-gradient(135deg,  rgba(233, 30, 99, 1) 0%, rgba(156, 39, 176, 1) 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#E91E63', endColorstr='#9C27B0',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 fallback on horizontal gradient */
}
.grad6 {
    background: rgb(156, 39, 176);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg,  rgba(156, 39, 176, 1) 0%, rgba(101, 201, 222, 1) 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */// rgba(156, 39, 176, 1) #9C27B0 | rgba(101, 201, 222, 1) #65C9DE
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg,  rgba(156, 39, 176, 1) 0%, rgba(101, 201, 222, 1) 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
    background: linear-gradient(135deg,  rgba(156, 39, 176, 1) 0%, rgba(101, 201, 222, 1) 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#9C27B0', endColorstr='#65c9de',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 fallback on horizontal gradient */
}
.home-big-gradient {
    /*this is changed to block in desktop below around line 337*/
    display: none;
}
```

Any help here would be amazing. I've read lots of comments about this not being possible but those are mostly from 2 to 5 years ago. There's got to be some kind of plugin or workaround out there. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Have a look at css transitions

Comment: First, make a working snippet so we have with what to work, second, you can't use single line comments in CSS (`// bla bla`), it has to be multi line (`/* bla bla */`)

Comment: I'm using scss, not css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

background gradient doesn't support `transition` but you could hack this creating another `div` that has a `z-index` bigger than your body or what contain your gradient but a lower `z-index` then the page content and `opacity:0` so you can apply the gradient to this `div` then make it visible and finally apply the gradient to the `body`, delete it from the `div` and hide it.

I know that from this aswere you don't get how to do this so this [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/3vqsztph/2/) will help you.

However I don't advice to use this strategy to avoid background gradient transition and keep the site as it is now.

Comment: Thank you paolobasso! Your solution works as best as it seems possible. I agree that this solution is minimally so. I'll need 7 of these transitions to take place on the same page so the DOM would be going crazy. I'll show this to the client and see if they want me to do it anyways or leave it as is. Thanks again Sir!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [ScrollReveal.js](https://github.com/jlmakes/scrollreveal)? You should be able to customize it to be able to transition the different backgrounds. And it would allow you to control the transitions by setting the `delay` property. I've used this library in some of my web pages and it's very easy to use, and you can pass it almost any element.